# PHP not rendering out on specific page

Tags: php, wordpress, woothemes

You can see on this page: http://oaktreehealth.ca/community/
That the PHP is not rendering out for some reason. I have the same function enabled on most other pages where you see the image in the background at the top of the page.

I'm not sure why all of a sudden it stopped rendering on this page? It was working fine, maybe a wordpress update?. I'm using wooththemes Canvas with a child theme. The only difference with this page is that it is a modified template of the blog template.

The area causing trouble is called in my functions to grab the template part. All other pages do this fine except this one. Any idea?

I'm not entirely sure how to add code in here, but i'm happy to send anything along to help.

Comment: You seem to have some encoding issues on your website, cnb you send us a snippet of your code so we could try to look for the problem ?

Comment: if you show the code is better...

Comment: how do I add the code? it says it's too long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you've linked, seems to have encoding issues, i believe due to white spaces before the php tag, if you inspect the source, you can see:

```
��<?php
```

Check the script corresponding to the following comment (as per the source):

```
/**
 * Template part for Media Feature Area
 */
```

And try to remove all whitespaces at the beginning and end of the script.

Comment: Yes, I thought that might be the case, but when I looked, there was no white spaces. I even replacd the content with contented that works and renderes on other pages with no luck.

Comment: Make sure that the encoding of that file is utf-8 without BOM

Comment: utf-8 did it! Not sure why it was utf-16??

Comment: Thank you thank you! Now i'm not sure how it changed though?? strange. Again it was working and then one day it wasn't without any changes.

Comment: You probably changed your IDE or code editor or the one you where using got reconfigured to save the files as utf-16 :)

Comment: ah ha.... I just got a new mac and re-installed my FTP clients... pehaps thats why. Thank you again!

Comment: that should be the issue, check the FTP client setting so that it uploads files with the proper encoding. And you are welcome :)